# Cannot be used across assembly boundaries because it has a generic type parameters that is an embedded interop type

Tags: vb.net

I am facing this error on changing a Sub to a Function in VB.Net

**Type System.Collection.Generic.List(Of mshtml.IHTMLDocument2) cannot be used across assembly boundaries because it has a generic type parameters that is an embedded interop type**.

Does anyone knows how to get it resolved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Changing the return type from List(Of mshtml.IHTMLDocument2) to **IList(Of mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)** or **IEnumerable(Of mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)** resolves the issue.

Comment: It fixes it because you no longer have a reference to the type, just an interface that the type implements.

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this by making sure that all assemblies had "Embed Interop Types" to FALSE.

It seems that usually when you use a COM library that parameter is set to true by default.

Comment: I would upvote this if you explained what "Embed Interop Types" actually means/does. Not that I couldn't look it up myself, but I don't think assembly-property changes with the potential for far-reaching implications should be recommended frivolously.

Comment: @Lopsided it's not recommended frivolously.  it's recommended to people who are getting the OP's error.  I don't think this recommendation could get any more directed than that.

Comment: When I attempted this solution it broke my library as I get the following error: Non-invocable member 'IHTMLElement.children' cannot be used like a method. So this may fix the OP's issue but to @Lopsided 's point it does have side effects.

Comment: JasonS making this change has side-effects beyond just fixing the OP's error. There are other considerations. Otherwise we could just set EmbedInteropTypes to False in all circumstances. Sometimes it needs to be True. I think that's what @Ross is getting at.